# user.identity.name becames Blank after a while

Tags: .net, asp.net

does anyone know why user.identity.name becames blank after a while about (10 mins), i am using .Net Framework 1.1

Edit: 
Session Timeout is set to 20 min

no timeout is set under system.web/authentication/forms in web.config

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason of this was because anonymous logon was enabled on IIS. i dont know how it was working the first minutes

Answer (score 1):

Session expiry is not related to ASP.NET authentication.

It could be your forms authentication is timing out: the default is 30 minutes, and it's configured using the timeout attribute of the system.web/authentication/forms element in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see how often the application pool is recycling? If its not set to recycle after certain time, it could be experiencing heavy load and therefore reaching the limit and recycling. At this point you would lose your session.

Also, how are you assigning the user.identity.name? If its via authentication, are the users also losing their authentication or just the name?

Comment: And so does the user lose their authentication as well or only the name clears? .IsAuthenticated returns false?