# user.identity.name and authenticationtype blank in mvc 3 with windows authentication after about 2 minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using windows authentication in my mvc 3 app and usually everything works fine. However, if i leave a certain page up for about 2 minutes, and then make an ajax request, the User.Identity.Name (in the controller) returns blank, as does the authenticationtype. This causes a failure when i check user.isinrole(whatever). Usually clearing the cache will fix the problem, but not regular refreshing. Sometimes i need to clear the cache a few times.

I am using chrome, and didn't notice the bug when I tried in IE (I haven't tried waiting longer than it takes in chrome), so is it possible the bug is with chrome?
EDIT: It happens in firefox too.

I noticed the time to failure was similar to the issue in [User.Identity.Name sometimes blank with Windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675593)
 but i did not see anything about anonymous authentication in my web.config

in [user.identity.name becames Blank after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363358) the problem seemed to be that anonymous authentication is enabled on their IIS server, and I have that too, but I wanted it set on my server. There are certain pages that need to be accessed anonymously, so the authentication is all enforced by MVC and not by the server, so IIS has anonymous and windows authentication enabled

I have authentication mode="Windows" in my system.web tag, and nothing about authorization in web.config. In the registerglobals function in global.asax.cs, i have

```
filters.Add(new RequireWindowsAuth());
```

that's a class that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute, and it overrides the OnAuthorization method to do something like the following

```
if(!User.IsInRole("Admin") && AdminAttr is defined)
     filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(403, "You are not authorized to view this page");
else if(AllowAnonymousAttribute is not found)
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
```

when the error happens, i get that exact 403 response from the server.

the action requested has the admin attr and not the allowanonymous attr defined on it

here is how i check for attrs being defined

```
filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(attr, true) || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AdminAttribute), true)
```

Comment: anything sent over in the headers for auth on this ajax request? Does the server send a challenge back for auth if nothing is sent the first time?

Comment: the headers are all the same in the request that works and the request that doesnt. there's nothing about auth as far as i can tell. theres accept, accept-charset, accept-encoding, accept-language, connection, content-length, cookie, host, origin, referer, user-agent, and x-requested-with. the server just sends back the 403 respose. I don't think it's sending back a challenge for auth. how would i be able to tell?

Comment: place a break point before the if condition and check whether the Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is set to true or false. If it was not set to true then either the user was logged of or may be some where you messed with logoff code.

Comment: it was not authenticated, but i have not controlled the logon and logoff. it just uses windows authentication so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Windows authentication doesn't use session state, does it? What you're describing sounds an awful lot like session timeout!

Comment: @bdwain Does the Action you are calling through ajax allow anonymous? And is the page/action you are calling the ajax request from allowing anonymous?

Comment: What version of IIS is hosting your application,IIS express, IIS 7.0 etc..?

Answer (score 1):

I would bring up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and connect it between the MVC app and the browser and monitor every piece of information that goes to-from browser-server.

1. Is the app-pool is restarted which causes it to forget about everybody that authenticated?
2. Either the security for any reason times out and the security cookie expires (or is lost)?
3. Check that the Session is not reset (use the Session_Start and Session_End Global events and log this somewhere)?

Fiddler should allow you to eliminate the client, which is a must - you are debugging a problem with too many components. You want to make sure that whatever browser you are using is passing clean and complete data. Eliminate either the browser, or the server from the problem.

My gut feeling tells me that either the server is forgetting about the authenticated user (which is detectable using Session_End, Application_End and logging it) because of a server issue and/or the AJAX somehow doesn't send the necessary information to continue to keep the authentication cookie alive. Fiddler will assist you in figuring out which of the two it is.

Bonus, Fiddler can allow you to replay a session - which will then allow you to reproduce the error - if it happens within Fiddler without a browser - you know the problem is on the server - otherwise - it's the browser/ajax.

Hope this helps,